# Some character is missing when I attempt to set TextPath align center in SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Some character is missing when I use `startOffset` or `text-anchor` attributes.
How to fix it.
Thanks.

---

In this case, characters `1234` is missing.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="width: 100%;"><svg width="1000" height="1000" x="0%" y="0%" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,500,500)"><g font-size="40" font-weight="800"><rect width="300" height="300" x="350" y="350" fill="#ffddff"></rect><path d="M 500,500 m -100,0 a 100,100 0 1,0 200,0 a 100,100 0 1,0 -200, 0" fill="transparent" stroke="black" id="SvgjsPath1000"></path><text svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}"><textPath xlink:href="#SvgjsPath1000" fill="url(&quot;#SvgjsLinearGradient1001&quot;)" startOffset="25%" text-anchor="middle" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}"><tspan alignment-baseline="middle">1234567890ABCDEFGHIJK</tspan></textPath></text></g></svg><defs><linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="SvgjsLinearGradient1001"><stop stop-color="#007cf0" offset="0"></stop><stop stop-color="#ff0080" offset="1"></stop></linearGradient></defs></svg>
```

I want to let these characters align center in Circle.
Like this:
[image: like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle that was generated (I assume) by svg.js was being drawn from the left side first. As an attribute `textPath` begins in relation to the starting point of the path so you can either use `textOffset` and look for magic numbers to get your text in the right spot, or you can start your circle from the top.

In the snippet I started the path from the top of where center is (just flipping the x and y values of the first relative move command) and flipped the `dx` and `dy` values of both arc commands.

The final control you need at that point is setting `startOffset` to 50% it comes pretty close to the image you shared and will stay centered to the bottom regardless of font size or string length.

In the snippet I also removed all the extra code that was injected. If this SVG is not for inline use you'll want to put xmlns back in there, not needed if used inline... also if you need all the additional markup provided by svg.js for some reason you should put that back in too.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="width: 100%;">
  <g font-size="40" font-weight="800">
    <rect width="300" height="300" x="350" y="350" fill="#ffddff"></rect>
    <path d="M 500,500
             m 0,-100
             a 100,100 0 1,0 0,200
             a 100,100 0 1,0 0, -200
            " 
          fill="transparent" stroke="black" id="circlePath">
    </path>
    <text>
      <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="url('#gradient')" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
        <tspan alignment-baseline="middle">1234567890ABCDEFGHIJK</tspan>
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </g>
<defs>
  <linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="gradient">
    <stop stop-color="#007cf0" offset="0"></stop>
    <stop stop-color="#ff0080" offset="1"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we expected. I think the key point is `flipped the dx and dy values of both arc commands`.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="width: 100%;"><svg width="1000" height="1000" x="0%" y="0%" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,500,500)"><g font-size="26" font-weight="800"><rect width="300" height="300" x="350" y="350" fill="#ffddff"></rect><path d="M 500,500 m -100,0 a 100,100 0 1,0 200,0 a 100,100 0 1,0 -200, 0" fill="transparent" stroke="black" id="SvgjsPath1000"></path><text svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}"><textPath xlink:href="#SvgjsPath1000" fill="url(&quot;#SvgjsLinearGradient1001&quot;)" startOffset="25%" text-anchor="middle" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}"><tspan alignment-baseline="middle">1234567890ABCDEFGHIJK</tspan></textPath></text></g></svg><defs><linearGradient x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" id="SvgjsLinearGradient1001"><stop stop-color="#007cf0" offset="0"></stop><stop stop-color="#ff0080" offset="1"></stop></linearGradient></defs></svg>
```

Comment: I want to set characters align center. And I modified the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is it okay if we decrease the font-size?

Comment: As long as the characters is long enough, this problem always needs to be faced